# In $n$ dimensions, why do we need at least $n+1$ sample points to have covariance of sample data non-singular?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, statistics

In $n$  dimensions, why do we need at least  $n+1$  sample points to have covariance of sample data non-singular?

[image]